# Connection was forcibly closed by a peer. in thunder client

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, thunderclient

```
when i enter request Url post request : https://localhost:8080/api/register getting an output like : Connection was forcibly closed by a peer. 
i also Off window firewall but their is no difference solve this issue when you also facing this.
this issue i getting in thunder client.
```

Expecting a response as i also entering some json in body of thunder client extension.

Comment: Try these solutions - https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/common-issues.md

Comment: I tried a lot a and also different version thunder client but cant work for me 